# activate onclick only when minlength=8 how to do that ?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```html
<p><input name="message" type="password" minlength="8" required style="font-size:50;width: 70%;" /></p>
<p><input onclick="this.value='Connecting please wait...' "class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enter" /></p>
```

how to only activate onclick the the value "enter" will be  "Connecting please wait..." only when  minlength is 8

Comment: Test pending `onclick="return this.form.message.value.length >= 8 ? this.value = 'Connecting please wait...' : false"`

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the handler properly using Javascript instead, and select and check the `password` field's value's `length`:

```js
const passwordInput = document.querySelector('input[type="password"]');
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]')
.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (passwordInput.value.length >= 8) this.value = 'Connecting please wait...';
});
```

```html
<p><input name="message" type="password" minlength="8" required style="font-size:50;width: 70%;" /></p>
<p><input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enter" /></p>
```

Comment: I would change `8` to `passwordInput.getAttribute('minlength')`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attribute `minlength` of the input and use that to test the length of the text entered like this:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('[type=submit]')
let input = document.querySelector('[type=password]')
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Get the minlength of the input field
  let minlen = input.getAttribute('minlength') || 8
  // If the input length is less than the minlength prevent submission
  if (input.value.length < minlen) e.preventDefault()
  // Else display the content
  else this.value = 'Connecting please wait...'
})
```

```html
<p><input name="message" type="password" minlength="8" required style="font-size:50;width: 70%;" /></p>
<p><input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enter" /></p>
```

**Note:** It has become less common to place your javascript within the html like you did. I would recommend moving it to its own file or between `script` tags

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onkeypress attribute on the password field which calls a JavaScript function to check whether 8 characters have been entered, if so add an event listener to the button via JS.

```
    <input type="password" onkeypress="checkLength(this)">
<button id="button">Button</button>
<script>
function checkLength(e) {
if (e.length > 7) {
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", functionToCall());
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><input name="message" type="password" minlength="8" required style="font-size:50;width: 70%;" /></p>
<p><input onclick="activate(this)" class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enter" /></p>
<script>
    function activate(ele) {
        var pEle = document.getElementsByName("message")[0];
        if(pEle.value.length >= pEle.minLength){
            ele.value = "Connecting, Pls wait...";
        }
    }
</script>
```